# What are the differences between Windows Desktop C# Apps and just apps?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications

Here are two similar articles:

1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast

2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop

I can't get info one thing. First article provides tutorial for notifications for **apps**. Another article shows tutorial for **Desktop C# app**. What to choose and what are the differences? Thanks.

Comment: They're talking about UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps vs non-UWP apps using older APIs like Win32, WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they call them apps like what they mean that are the apps made with the new technology called UWP (Universal Windows Platform) which only work with Windows 10. You can see it here.

> Prerequisites
>
> To fully understand this topic, the following will be helpful...
>
> ```
> A working knowledge of toast notification terms and concepts. For more information, see Toast and action center overview.
> A familiarity with Windows 10 toast notification content. For more information, see toast content documentation.
> A Windows 10 UWP app project
> ```

Then what they call Desktop C# app, are the "classic" ways to do windows applications. For example WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) in C# which runs in most Windows machines, like Windows 7 or Vista, also they meant the application made in c++.

The main difference is that what they call **apps** are the ones made with UWP, these ones work well on windows tables, windows phones, and so on.
And **desktop c# app**
 is an app created with WPF which is a little older but works in older OS's.